# get value of dynamically changed asp.net label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web, controls

I have an asp.net label web control. I change its text dynamically using jQuery .html() function. When I try to source the present value of a label on the server it displays the very original one from when the page loaded. Is there any way I could make the jQuery changes to the label permanent so I could source them on the server?

Comment: Change it on serverside.

Comment: Can you put more detail - why is this a problem when the page hasn't posted back. If you are just doing it on page load then do as other commenter has said and set in server side. Why does it need to be on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to mirror you JQuery changes into another control that will perist on the server side.

For example use a hidden field that is mared `runat="server"` Shadow your change into this then this will persist on the server i.e. read the label change from the hidden field

so

**JQuery**

```
$('#labelID').html('New Text');

$('#hiddenFieldID').val('New Text');
```

**Server Side**

```
string labelText = hiddenFieldID.value;
```

It's not pretty but it's the only way I've found of doing it.

JQuery doesn't interact with `ViewState` hence any changes with JQuery are lost on postback. It's one of the reasons I think that people are now going towards MVC. The postback architecture doesn't play well with client side changes

Comment: good idea, but this would only work if there will be postback on the server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this out of the box (although I could be wrong). The issue is that a label isn't a HTML form field, so it's value isn't sent back to the server on postback, so either the ViewState value will be used, or the default value, rather than the updated value.

You could hack something together where you also set the label value in a hidden field, which WILL get sent back to the server on postback and use that to populate the value of the label on postback if it's been changed?